# GKE Ingress pointing to ExternalName service doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

First of all, what I want to build is right below.
[image]

as above diagram, I want Ingress to make distribute traffics to service which is at other namespace `me` in same cluster. (Ingress is in `main` namespace) But the Ingress doesn't allow to point dns directly, I make ExternalName Service that points to `me-service` dns `me-service.me.svc.cluster.local` and then Ingress points to it.

Yaml of it is

main.k8s.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: main
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: me-service
  namespace: main
spec:
  externalName: me-service.me.svc.cluster.local
  type: ExternalName
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
  name: main-router
  namespace: main
spec:
  rules:
  - host: some-domain.me
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: me-service
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

me.k8s.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  labels:
    stag: production
  name: me
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service  # <-- this is the service I want to point
metadata:
  labels:
    app: me
    stag: production
  name: me-service
  namespace: me
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: me
    stag: production
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: me
    stag: production
  name: me-deployment
  namespace: me
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: me
      stag: production
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: me
        stag: production
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/me:latest
        name: me
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 512M
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 512M
```

And I checked dns address works but Ingress object doesn't created with error message

```
me-service:80 (<error: endpoints "me-service" not found>)
 Type     Reason     Age                    From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                     -------
  Warning  Translate  6m21s (x233 over 22h)  loadbalancer-controller  Translation failed: invalid ingress spec: could not find port "80" in service "main/me-service"
```

How can I make ingress work? If you need more information, please let me know. :pray:

GKE Engine: **1.20.6-gke.1000**

HTTP Load Balancing: **Enabled**

Network policy: **Disabled**

Dataplane V2: **Enabled**

Comment: As far as I know you cannot use **GKE ingress** with `ExternalName` Service type. The two supported types are `LoadBalancer` and `NodePort`. If nothing changed recently, you shouldn't be able to create an ingress resource even with a simple `ClusterIP`, only two above mentioned svc types so I don't believe that `ExternalName` would work. Well, you can actually use `ClusterIP` but only if you use [container native load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/container-native-load-balancing) which requires your **GKE** cluster to be VPC-native.

Comment: @mario Thank you for your comment. Then you mean load balancing to other namespace is actually not possible as long as I use GKE, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. You can still use **GKE** but don't have to use GCE ingress as an ingress controller at the same time. But I would try first if it doesn't work with the mentioned container-native load balancing. You can always deploy different ingress controller on your **GKE** cluster e.g. nginx-ingress. It can use `ClusterIP` services out of the box, but I'm not sure if it can handle the `ExternalName` so you would have to try this out.

Comment: @mario Thank you for your comment. I successfully distribute traffics to other namespace svc using NGINX-ingress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm posting it as an answer for better visibility. As I already mentioned in my comments:*

As far as I know you cannot use **GKE ingress** with `ExternalName` Service type. The two supported types are `LoadBalancer` and `NodePort`. If nothing changed recently, you shouldn't be able to create an ingress resource even with a simple `ClusterIP`, only two above mentioned svc types so I don't believe that `ExternalName` would work. Well, you can actually use `ClusterIP` but only if you use [container native load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/container-native-load-balancing) which requires your **GKE** cluster to be VPC-native.

You can still use **GKE** but you don't have to use **GCE ingress** as an ingress controller at the same time. But I would try first if it doesn't work with the mentioned container-native load balancing.

You can always deploy **different ingress controller on your **GKE** cluster e.g. nginx-ingress**. It can use `ClusterIP` services out of the box, but I'm not sure if it can handle the `ExternalName` so you would have to try this out.

OP confirmed that with **nginx-ingress** it was possible to distribute traffic to services located in different namespaces:

> @mario Thank you for your comment. I successfully distribute traffics
> to other namespace svc using NGINX-ingress. – HyeonJunOh Jul 23 at
> 9:23